# Incompatible type when type is in the union of allowed types?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I'm attempting to figure out why mypy doesn't like this call and signature combination given the following error message

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[List[Any], Dict[Any, Any], bytes, str, int, float]", variable has type "Dict[Any, Any]")
```

A call of

```
to_json = self._format_types(to_json)
```

With a function signature of

```
def _format_types(
    self,
    to_format: Union[List, Dict]) -> Union[
        List, Dict, bytes, str, int, float]:
```

Answer (score 0):

If `to_json` was previously inferred to be of type `Dict[Any, Any]`, that means it surely ought to be type-safe to write code like this:

```
to_json = self._format_types(to_json)
print(to_json.items())  # Danger!
```

But what if your `_format_types` method returns an int instead of a `Dict[Any, Any]`? That would cause the above program to crash, so mypy reports the assignment is unsafe.

If you're absolutely sure that the specific way that you're invoking `self._format_types` will always produce a dict, you assert that's the case:

```
temp = self._format_types(to_json)
assert isinstance(temp, dict)
to_json = temp
print(to_json.items())  # Safe!
```

...or if you prefer one-liners and/or don't want the overhead of *actually* performing a runtime check, just cast the expression:

```
from typing import cast

# ...snip...

to_json = cast(Dict[Any, Any], self._format_types(to_json))
print(to_json.items())  # Also reported as safe!
```

Alternatively, you can try using the [`--allow-redefinition` flag](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#miscellaneous-strictness-flags), which will make mypy widen the type of `to_json` when it's reassigned, under certain conditions.

So that would modify the behavior of mypy to do the following:

```
def blah(self, to_json: Dict[Any, Any]) -> None:
    # This will continue to type check
    print(to_json.items())

    # Previously this would have caused an error; mypy will instead alter
    # the type of `to_json` to be your union if you use --allow-redefinition
    to_json = self._format_types(to_json)

    # And now, mypy will report an error since List, int, etc don't have
    # an 'item()' method:
    print(to_json.items())
```

Comment: It's a recursive function where the final call should always produce a dictionary or list but my end conditions are if you hit an int, str, byte, or float. I'll probably add more types in the future like IPv4Address, IPv6Address, and UUID.